Does updating Cygwin 32-bit to 64-bit require Cygwin client update?
We have systems using Cygwin 32-bit application. Now we have to update it to 64-bit due to the server changes. Does this require the Cygwin client to be updated as well?
Thanks for any helps!

Yes, but check the cygwin web site or the mailing list for a more authoritative answer.
